# Finding the log of the product of two terms of an unknown arithmetic sequence.

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Consider a geometric progression and an arithmetic progression with the following characteristics:

1- The geometric progression has a term equal to $1$ and the ratio is positive real number, $q,$ different than $1.$

2- The arithmetic progression has a term equal $0$ and the ratio, $r$, is a rational number which does not equal zero.

3- The two sequences are in bijective correspondence, such that the term $1$ of the geometric progression is associated with the term $0$ from the arithmetic progression.

Consider that the number $A$ in the arithmetic progression is associated with the number $23$ of the geometric progression. Consider also a number $B$ of the arithmetic progression associated with the number $30$ in the geometric progression.

What is the value of the Logarithm of $A$ times $B$?

---

So far I have written the terms of the GP and AP as such:
$$GP: 1, q, q^2, q^3, \ldots, 23, \ldots, 30, \ldots$$
$$GA: 0, r, 2r, 3r, \ldots, A, \ldots, B, \ldots$$

Where:
\begin{align}
q^m &= 23\\
q^n &= 30\\
A &= mr\\
B &= nr
\end{align}

$$\log(AB) = \log(m)+ \log(n)+2\log(r)$$

I don't know how to follow through.

**The answer to the problem is $53$**.

Comment: It is not possible for the terms $1$, $23$, and $30$ all to occur in the same geometric progression. Is it possible that these are supposed to be terms of the arithmetic sequence and $A$ and $B$ are in the geometric sequence? (Even then, I think there is something missing from the problem statement, as the answer seems indeterminate.)

Comment: arithmetic progression have a common difference, not a ratio..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you should have written the terms of the GP and AP as such:
$$GP: 1, q, q^2, q^3, \ldots, 23, \ldots, B, \ldots$$
$$GA: 0, r, 2r, 3r, \ldots, A, \ldots, 30, \ldots$$

Where:
\begin{align}
q^m &= 23\\
q^n &= B\\
A &= mr\\
30 &= nr
\end{align}

Try going on from there.